# RuntimeCamelException due to org.apache.cxf.feature.Feature not present

Tags: spring, web-services, cxf, apache-camel, x509

I am trying example given at http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example.html  My configuration is like

'

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="cxfTutorialWebService"
                   address="/CXFTutorialWebService"
                   serviceClass="com.example.tutorial.ws.TutorialWebServiceImpl"
                   wsdlURL="wsdl/TutorialService.wsdl"
                   serviceName="c:TutorialWebService"
           endpointName="c:TutorialWebService"                 xmlns:c="http://example.com/tutotial/TutorialWebService/">
          <cxf:properties>
            <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="keystorePasswordCallback"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value-ref="keystoreProperties"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value-ref="keystoreProperties"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="useReqSigCert"/>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
          </cxf:properties>
          <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
          </cxf:inInterceptors>

      <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
      </cxf:outInterceptors>
 </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

 <bean id="tutorialService" class="com.example.tutorial.ws.TutorialService"/>

 <camelContext id="test_context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
      <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:cxfTutorialWebService"/>
        <to uri="bean:tutorialService?method=processSoap"/>
      </route>
</camelContext>`
```

where `com.example.tutorial.ws.TutorialWebServiceImpl` is working fine with `jaxws:endpoint id="tutorialWebService"` But I want this web service request to invoke Camel route. So I am trying to create a `<cxf:cxfEndpoint>` as shown above. But I on starting the webapp in Tomcat I am getting exception as

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxfTutorialWebService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.cxf.feature.Feature not present
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(ApplicationContextRegistry.java:47) ~[camel-spring-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:63) ~[camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.cxf.feature.Feature not present
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:94) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:291) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:387) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:114) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:72) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:56) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1130) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:414) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:161) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:248) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:395) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:161) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:224) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:149) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:305) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:312) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.feature.Feature
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.41]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
... 73 common frames omitted
```

I could not find which jar to get `org.apache.cxf.feature.Feature` Please provide some suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Which version of CXF are you using?

Comment: I am using CXF version 2.4.0. One more thing is I am using the same interfaces generated by plugin `jaxws-import` used for `jaxws:endpoint` with `cxf:cxfEndpoint` also, For `serviceClass` attribute. Should I have to use interfaces generated by `codegen-wsdl2java` in cxf for `cxf:cxfEndpoint` ?

Comment: As the Feature class is just used by CXF, I suppose you need to use to SEI class which is generated by CXF.

Comment: I am using the generated code from codegen plugin from CXF. The code works fine for jaxws:endpoint but gives error in case of using cxf:cxfEndpoint with Camel Route

Comment: That's strange, can you check the version of Camel and CXF?

Comment: I am using CXF version 2.4.0 and camel Version 2.13.0 and spring version 3.0.5.RELEASE. Is there any compatibility matrix as such available for CXF-Spring-Camel application

Comment: Camel 2.13.0 is using CXF 2.7.x for testing, can you change the CXF version to 2.7.11?

Comment: Its working with CXF version 2.7.10 Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it using CXF Version of 2.7.10. Not sure of exact incompatibility issues but using

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

on project revealed Camel was using CXF version of 2.7.10 even though I was using 2.4.0. So I updated it to 2.7.10 and I suppose some incompatibility is fixed